# load data from text with pandas with a two characters as separator

Tags: pandas, load

I'm trying to load data with pandas from a txt table.
The column separator was defined as "|@" as you can see in the example:

LINEA DE NEGOCIO|@NOMBRE CLIENTE|@NUMERO CLIENTE|@NUMERO DE CONTRATO|@TIPO DE SEGURO

The system does not allow to use "|@" as separator.

Could you help me with this loading?

Thanks in advance.

I share the code:

```
df = pd.read_table('D:/Art_492/Encabezado.txt', sep='|@', index_col=0).astype(str)
```

Comment: `pd.read_table(data,sep='\|@',engine='python',index_col=0).astype(str)` should work.

Comment: You could also do just with `@` and remove the last element in each entry (but previous comment is cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

The `|` represents `OR` operator in regular expression, you need to escape it using `\` so updating your regex string to `\|@` and setting `engine='python'` you can get your desired result.

```
pd.read_table(data,sep='\|@',engine='python',index_col=0).astype(str)
```